# Validation username and password with some condtion

Tags: python-3.x

So I have to create code that validates (ask username and password) whether a password:

```
Contains at least 1 number
Contains at least 1 capital letter
Contains at least 1 small letter
Contains at least 1 special symbol
```

and again ask the username and password (the previous one that we entered) if enter the wrong one after 3rd attempt it will print account blocked!

Comment: what code have you tried already? This site is more about helping you fix code that isn't working; it is not about providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the contains statements. I know you can just assign a variable += 1 every time they enter an incorrect or invalid password until that variable hits a certain number (3). Then it would print out a statement that says something along the lines of "Blocked".

Comment: Hey, try to add code sample to explain your answer. That'll make your answer easy to understand. Otherwise, this could easily have been a comment instead of the answer.